# How To Prevent Duplicate Rows In MySQL with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert, innodb, myisam

I wrote a simple system that collects data about users in my site.

For each new user, my client side code (Javascript) creates a unique id, stores it in a cookie, and sends all the data to the server with this unique id identifier.

On the server, I have the following PHP code that checks if this user exist in the USERS table, and if it does it will use that user id for other data inserts and if not it will create a new user:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT User_ID FROM USERS WHERE Unique_ID=:uid");
$stmt->bindValue(':uid', $_GET['unique_id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();               

if ($row) {
    ///// This user exists in USERS Table
    $User_ID = $row['User_ID'];
}
else
{
   /////INSERT a new user to USERS table with this Unique_ID
}
```

After running this on the live site, I sometimes get multiple entries in USERS table with the same Unique_ID.

I checked further and these duplicated user rows are written with less than 1 second apparat. So I think it happens when the client's browser sends 2 data requests at once (which ok and typical for my application logic).

I tried to change the USERS table engine from INNODB to MYISAM - to enforce table locking instead of row locking - It didn't help.

To prevent duplicate values, I know that I can add a Unique index to the Unique_ID field or do an "INSERT IGNORE ON DUPLICATE" - But these options will not return the right user row when I need it.

Any idea what I should do here?

Thanks!

Comment: This should be setup when you create the table. Edit: Check out `AUTO_INCREMENT` with `PRIMARY KEY`s [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

Comment: Why not add such an index? Why let the frontend generate the IDs if it does not check whether they are already in use?

Comment: If you want to stick to the process that the frontend generates the IDs - please share details for that. If two clients generate the same ID within seconds, you need to adjust that algorithm

Comment: *But these options will not return the right user row when I need it.* INSERT returns rows never. This does not depend of the original value or duplicate was inserted.

Comment: To Clarify - 2 clients will NEVER generate the same ID (very very unlikely), this is not my problem. My problem is that I get 2 entries in my DB for the Same user even though I preform the check I showed in my code.

Comment: Why do you send multiple requests to insert the same user?

Comment: Make the column unique

Comment: Also, have you checked what your code really does? Why do you try to read an array element at the key `User_ID` which is not part of the field list in your `SELECT` query?

Comment: I'm sending data streams from the browser, and I send them with a Unique ID that is generated on the client.

Comment: And why do you send such "data streams" multiple times to insert a user?

Comment: I'm sending data stream from the browser according the stuff my client code needs to do to, sometimes they will be 20 seconds apart and sometimes less than 1 second apart. And I always send the unique user id to know on the server who sent it. If this is a new user I will create it, if not - I shouldn't. The problem is that when 2 data streams comes from the same user in less than 1 seconds - I get 2 identical entries in the USERS table

Comment: Then you should not send out these "data streams" too often. Why not wait between them?

Comment: I can't wait between them, this is an important part of my apps logic. Any idea why I get duplicated row of the same user? Isn't this extra weird?

Comment: it's not weird, you have 2 calls on your php script at the same-ish time, and both fail the initial `SELECT` and run the `else` block. It probably won't happen often, but it will happen at some point

Comment: Thanks @Pepper ! unfortunately in my case it happens a lot (about 10% of my users) which is really not optimal for my data collection. Any idea how I can prevent this?

Comment: There are 3 places you can deal with it: Client side (spacing your requests), php side (semaphores/monitors or scheduling) and database side (unique index or transaction/stored procedure). IMO (and according to the comments) out of those the best and simplest is a unique index, but you need to change your php script a bit

Comment: The idea would be to `select`, if no user found: `insert ignore`, if insert worked: get the lastInsertID, else `select` again (1 query if all goes well, 3 for the worst case). Or alternatively always `insert ignore` at the start of your script, then `select` (always 2 queries, even if the user already exists)

Comment: Thanks @Pepper, I also think that adding a unique index is the best solution, however, if my SELECT query doesn't retrieves an existing user - I'm not able to handle this user later in the code - So the unique index will only prevent duplicates, but wont help me store more data on other tables for this user. Is PHP+MYSQL that primitive? I'm really surprised!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226084/discussion-between-siteappdev-and-pepper).

Comment: If you change your php code to follow one of the two "algorithms" of my last comment, you should never have a case where `$User_ID` is undefined. (edit: sorry, I can't chat, have to go :)

Comment: Thanks @Pepper I like your idea - trying it now.

Comment: @Pepper please do not post resolving advice in comments. This can lead to question abandonment and other bad outcomes. If you have insights to resolve the question, then all of that needs to be consolidated into a single coherent uninterrupted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given all you have said about needing to maintain the way that your app works you should use a Queue. You can either create your own where these requests get logged in another table and then processed by (a new version of) this function from the table in order - one at a time. Or use a SAS queue like AWS SQS. That will solve your issue and maintain the processes as you have them.

Comment: That's a good idea, I can do that but before I go in that route, I want to understand more about this issue, because I'm very surprised about these duplicated inserts. Do you have any idea why the table lock is not sufficient here? Also, to test things, I created a JS loop on my browser that sends 5 of these requests to my server with the same unique id at once and I couldn't reproduce the problem - but it keeps happening from my visitors.

Comment: I think the issue is that the check for the duplicate is done first and that will generate a response when the table is locked as its just a read. So your code checks for duplicates they are not there and then waits for the unlock and then writes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UUID()` (or the equivalent in the client) instead of the current time.

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned you have added checks for user ids & table level locks you are good there,

Your client sending multiple request to store data, that's the main issue you have.
The most common reason to that is, you must have some submit or save button on form that is sending request getting accidently or intentionally clicked twice.

Before sending request you need to use disable property for that button as user clicks that button which should stop your multiple click requests.

After that, if you still have issue & if you have to use JS for id generation, you can have workaround by logging every request to some log table with unprocessed status & have some cronjob to update/process these record one by one to your users table.

Comment: Thanks but that data is not sent by a form - it's a JS script that runs in the background and is collecting and sending this data.

Comment: What makes you think that there is any form involved?